# A file that cannot checked out or stash or commited

Tags: git

I am trying to `git pull` but I get :

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by merge:
>           database.sqlite3 Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

I tried `git checkout database.sqlite3` or `git stash` or even `git add -A` but this file still is there. In `git add -A` this guy is sitting both on staged files and on not staged at the same time:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   database.sqlite3
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   database.sqlite3
```

Any idea?

Comment: `git stash` followed by `git pull` should be fine, you can `git stash pop` after that and merge the pulled code with your local changes.

Comment: Have you tried `git add database.sqlite3`?

Comment: *[...] this guy is sitting both on staged files and on not staged at the same time*. If a file is listed under both "Changes to be committed" and "Changes not staged for commit", it means that it's a file tracked by Git that you modified then staged, then modified again, but without staging it afterwards. In other words, that file contains changes that have been staged, and others that haven't. Nothing alarming.

Comment: Commiting the file should work. What error do you get when you commit it? I don't mean to add it, and then commit. I mean just do: git commit database.sqlite3

Comment: One way or another, you have to get that file "out of the way". Git won't allow you to pull because those changes would get lost in the process. The question is: what do you want to do with those (staged and unstaged) changes? Commit them, stash them, or discard them?

Comment: Why in the world are you tracking sqlite3 database files with `git` to begin with?

Comment: all of these ways was working if I was not confused with a running process which created the file immediately when I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the issue origin was out of git hands. The issue was that whenever I did a `git checkout database.sqlite3` or `git stash` ... I checked git status and see the file is still there. The problem was as follows:
There was a uwsgi process which was running and it has a connection to database.sqlite3 and for some reasons it created database.sqlite3 file immidietly after I remove/checkout/etc the file.
I kill it by `killall -s INT uwsgi` and then a normal `git checkout database.sqlite3` and then `git pull -v`

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to commit the file, do the following:**

```
git commit -m 'database.sqlite3  changes' 
git add database.sqlite3
git commit -m 'database.sqlite3 more changes'
git push origin [branch-name]
```

The file has been changed twice, therefore the staged `database.sqlite3` needs to be committed. Then the change currently not staged needs to be committed separately.

**If you want to remove the changes in the file, do the following:**

```
git checkout database.sqlite3
git reset
git checkout database.sqlite3
```

The checkout step is repeated above because you need to get rid of two changes. To get to the state you are in, you probably changed a file, added it, then changed it again. This is why you are going to have to undo two changes.

After either of the above scenarios, you should be able to do git pull.

Comment: It was nice to see your answer but my problem was out of git hands. see my answer please!